# C++ builder - can't stylize the progress bar

Tags: progress-bar, c++builder, styling

The progress bar has properties such are "BackgroundColor", "BarColor", "Smooth" but none of them work on windows XP machine. The progress bar just ignores them. How can I use these properties properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties in question do not work when ComCtrl v6 Visual Styles are enabled in your app under XP and later.  Windows ignores the relevant `PBM_...` messages that are used.  MSDN documents that behavior.  There is no way around that, the visual theming controls the look and feel and you can't override that.  So you either need to disable theming, or find a third-party progress bar (or make your own) that supports what you need.